# Algorithm to find the distinct representations of the integer $n$ as a sum of $k$ non-negative p^(th) integer powers.

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, exponentiation, integers, integer-partitions

I am a user of Wolfram Mathematica and in that software there is a function called: [PowersRepresentations](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PowersRepresentations.html). This function returns lists of integers $0\le n_1\le n_2\le\dots\le n_k$ such that $n_1^p+n_2^p+\dots+n_k^p=n$

> Question: what algorithm does Mathematica uses to found the PowersRepresentations of a number.

---

I know that when dealing with sums of just integers (so not powers) we can use the [Partition function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_(number_theory)) found by Srinivasa Ramanujan. But is there also a formula/algorithm for the PowersRepresentations of a number?

Comment: The example you have linked is for cubes, i.e., for $p=3$. There we have many possibilities, e.g., generating functions (Ramanujan) and known parametrizations, for example $$\begin{align}
6x &= (x − 1 )^3 + (−x )^3 + (−x )^3 + (x + 1 )^3 \\
6x + 3 &= x^3 + (−x + 4 )^3 + (2x − 5 )^3 + (−2x + 4 )^3 \\
18x + 1 &= (2x + 14 )^3 + (−2x − 23 )^3 + (−3x − 26 )^3 + (3x + 30 )^3 \\
216x-16 &= (14742x^2 - 2157x + 82)^3 + (-14742x^2 + 2211x - 86)^3 + (4914x^2-971x+44)^3 + (-4914x^2+485x-8)^3 \\
216x+92 &= (3x-164)^3 + (-3x+160)^3+(x-35)^3 + (-x+71)^3
\end{align}$$

Comment: @DietrichBurde So, if I understand correctly there is not a 'closed' formula to compute find the possibilities?

Comment: No, there is no "closed" formula. It is not even known which integers are the sum of three cubes. Recently it was proved that $42$ is indeed the sum of three cubes (not necessarily positive).

Comment: @DietrichBurde I know that that is the case for positive and negative integers, but when we only want to look at the positive integers how does Mathematica compute them? Does it try every possible value (like a brute force method)?

Comment: That would be terribly inefficient, I suppose. But I didn't look into the Mathematica code. Why do you want to know this?

Comment: @DietrichBurde for big values the code is really slow so I thought maybe there is a mathematical 'trick' that someone can show me here to increase the computing time for bigger values instead of using the algorithm that Mathematica uses.